# How is the value character converted into integer?

Tags: c

Below is a source code of the program, and if the input is 97, the output is

```
Please enter a number between 97 and 121:97

The 1st output is: a
The 2nd output is: a
The 3rd output is b
The 4th output is 97
--------------------------------
```

What is the logic behind this output? How is an integer converted into character? is it [ASCII Chart](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii)?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main () 
{
    int a;
    printf("\n%s enter a number between 97 and 121:" , "Please");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("\nThe 1st outpit is: %c", a);
    printf("\nThe 2nd output is: %c" ,a++);
    printf("\nThe 3rd output is %c", a--);
    printf("\nThe 4th output is %d", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read about format specifiers.

Comment: You can easily figure out whether it's ascii by running the program multiple times with different inputs

Comment: Try `int b = 'a' and see what you get.

Comment: Tip: Text as only a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNaJ6.jpg) attracts down votes. Test posted as text is more useful.

Comment: Tip 2: Better to post true output rather than _almost true_ output.  It is little things like where is `"--------------------------------"` in code and `"The 1st outpit"` of code vs. `"The 1st output"` (`i` vs `u`) that hint to the unfaithfulness of a post and create unneeded confusion.  Best to cut and paste code,input, output, error messages, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is an integer converted into character?

Let us look at `"%d"` first.

```
printf("\nThe 4th output is %d", a);
```

`a` has the value of 97 at this point.  As `printf()` sees a `"%d"`, it expects to see an `int` as the next argument - which it is - good.  The *value* of 97 causes 2 characters to print: `'9'` and `'7'`.

> fprintf c
>    The `int` argument is converted to signed decimal in the style [−]dddd..
>   C11dr §7.21.6.1 8

---

Now `"%c"`.

```
printf("\nThe 1st outpit is: %c", a);
```

`a` has the value of 97 at this point.  As `printf()` sees a `"%c"`, it expects to see an `int` as the next argument - which it is - good.  Then the `int` value is converted to `unsigned char`, which is still value 97. Then the character corresponding to 97 is "printed".  This correspondence is overwhelming though  [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) for the values 0-127 and so a character 'a' is seen.

> ..., the `int` argument is converted to an `unsigned char`, and the resulting character is written.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the logic behind this output. How is an integer converted into character?

Contextually, you are asking how an integer is converted into a character *by `printf`*.  [The specifications for `printf`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p8) have this to say about the `%c` conversion specifier:

> If no l length modifier is present, the int argument is converted to
>   an unsigned char, and the resulting character is written.

The term "converted" there is talking about a *numeric* conversion, and since the target type is unsigned, the result is the original value if it is representable by the target type (as it is in your example).  If it were not representable as an `unsigned char`, then the result would be reduced modulo one more than the maximum representable `unsigned char` value.

But really, the thrust of the question seems to be how that number is mapped to a character.  In fact, C does not specify.  This is the question of the "execution character set", and C is fairly lax about that.  In practice, the execution character set is often a superset of ASCII, such as UTF-8-encoded Unicode or one of the ISO-8859 character sets, but it does not have to be.  It may even vary at runtime depending on the execution environment.

In your particular run, the output is consistent with an ASCII-compatible execution character set being in use, and that is almost certainly the case, but you could only tell *for sure* by verifying that the output matches ASCII for all code points mapped by ASCII (0 - 127, inclusive).

Answer (score 0):

Where as in the char data type value in C is implicitly convertible to an int data type for the following example,

```
char a = 'd'; 
printf("%d", a)
```

prints the decimal ASCII value of d that is 100.

---

When I ran your above code,

I just entered 100 that is d

```
$./a.out

Please enter a number between 97 and 121:100

The 1st outpit is: d <= a
The 2nd output is: d <= a++ (post increment, d->e)
The 3rd output is e  <= a-- (decrement e->d)
The 4th output is 100 <= ASCII value of d.
```

Answer (score -2):

As per your output ,you can find that when you print your integer value with %d format specifier,it prints as of your same integer value.But when you print it with %c format specifier your answer would be the ASCII character of the passed integer value.By default C compiler stores your character data in the form ASCII values.So it is the way you interpret your integer either as a character or an integer.For more details Visit https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx6a.html

Comment: C in no way promises to use an ASCII-compatible character encoding for the execution character set.  Nor does the page you linked say otherwise.  It is *common* for an ASCII-compatible encoding to be used, but it is not a default. And ASCII itself is never used *per se*, because ASCII is a 7-bit code and C `char`s are minimum 8 bits wide.